# Does a Solar Sorcerer need to be in contact with fire to receive its healing bonus at 5th level? (1st Ed.)

Tags: pathfinder-1e, sorcerer, bloodline

The Solar Bloodline in Pathfinder 1e gains a power at 3rd level called Friend of Fire (Su). It states:

> At 5th level, when in contact with flame or a burning object (including a *flaming* weapon, lantern, or torch), add 1 per die to any healing effect of which you are the target...

Does the sorcerer need to physically touch the burning part of these objects, or is it enough to simply hold them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Holding a burning object is sufficient

The bloodline ability specifies two triggers: contact with flame, or contact with a burning object. If you had to touch the burning part of a burning object, you'd be touching flames, which would make specifying both triggers redundant. So it seems pretty clear (to me) that holding a burning object, regardless of whether you are holding the burning part or not, suffices for the conditions of this ability.

Obviously, your GM may decide otherwise; it's probably wise to ask them in advance if you are planning on playing a Sorcerer with this bloodline.